# Как Selenium подключить к запущенному профилю chrome?

Tags: python, selenium

Вот есть браузер. Хром.

Вот в браузере хроме есть целиком настроенный под меня профиль. Закладки там, расширения и.т.п.

Вот есть я, который сидит и работает в запущенном браузере хроме в моем профиле.

Вот есть я, который хочет написать программу, которая по нажатию кнопки в гуе будет делать в нужной мне вкладке запущенного хрома нужные мне действия.

Может ли такое селениум? Или дядя иди гуляй?

Comment: Сорян за формулировки, чутка пригорело с того, что все что есть в интернете и называется как "подключаем селениум к существующему хрому" радостно начинается с "а давайте создадим новый профиль хрома! Вообще ничем не отличающийся от того что стартует через селениумплагин.ехе! И да, если не создать, то ничего не заработает!"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Селениум не запускается на рабочем профиле чтоб защитить Вас от вирусов, которые получат доступ к приватным данным и действиям на всех сайтах, обратившись к нему.

Для автоматизации пользовательских действий лучше напишите своё расширение.

Comment: Ясно-понятно. Спасибо за ответ. Пойду покурю как расширения делать.